# Looking for a word for a coward who claims credit for the heroic acts of others

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

Someone who doesn't do anything required or expected but takes credit for having performed heroic deeds.

I have considered 'cowardly', but it doesn't convey the complete meaning.

An example sentence:

> A _____ man found a doctor to write him an excuse to keep him out of the draft thus not meeting his duty but says he spent days digging people out of the ruins of the World Trade Center even though he was never there.

Comment: Please could you explain why 'cowardly' doesn't work? I assume it is because 'cowardly' doesn't imply taking credit, but please let us know your thoughts!

Comment: That blank does not require anything at all that conveys the complete meaning, or any part of the meaning, or any meaning at all. Because the situation is then explained in great detail in the sentence that follows. Why do you want to say the same thing twice over. Do not put any word at all in the blank, and you are done.

Comment: @RegDwigнt it's more emphatic with the unspecified adjective.

Comment: I'd go for an adjective that shows the person to be even viler than cowardly: dastardly. Sorry but there was no draft after 911. Sounds like you are historically mixed up.

Comment: I would describe him as "trumped up".